# Chatter "Groups" (or Queues) In Lieu Of Single Users?

Tags: administration, chatter, tag

I've **searched already** and **believe the answer is NO**, but thought I'd verify here with real-world users...

*Is there a way in Chatter to tag a "Group of users" (perhaps a Queue?) instead of or in addition to @User?*  I did notice (by simple testing) that there is a hash tagging system (I personally could care less about Chatter and don't use it as the Admin) via #tags, but no other tagging delimiters were discovered.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Chatter Group Mentions are not supported today, however there is an [App Exchange Beta App](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5HJs45m4jd) in the works.

Currently an [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Ku1gAAC).